# Help building a random name generator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csv, random

As a teacher I am looking to create a random name generator to use with my classes. I don't know much but I am willing to learn.
I want my random name generator to be able to load class lists from an external csv or txt file - I want the random name generator to be able to recognise the time and load the pre-defined class for that time of day. I think this will work best if the day and time were listed above each class list in the csv or txt file.
I will also look to add a basic action button which generates a new name when pressed. 
I have seen some posts referring to creating a random number generator and then link this to a text list but I think I am trying to do something a bit more different.
I am using Visual Studio Pro 2010 on Vista SP2 if that helps.
Cheers.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a language to use, how file format the names are in, or much else, besides the fact that you need help.  You may want to talk with some other students and see if someone can write this for you perhaps for some extra credit in a math class or something.

Comment: so your csv would have multiple days in it? show the format.

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for the replies so far.
I don't mind what language is used as I will be happy to learn it providing what I am proposing can be done.
As for the csv I was thinking along the lines of the day being at the top followed by times and then student names. Possible example:
Monday
8.45-9.45
Name1 surname1
Name2 surname2
etc.

Thank you to all that are taking their time to respond - I appreciate your time.

Comment: Good luck with that, but unfortunately it isn't a question. Sounds like you are looking for a consultant to do your project for you. Try eLance.com or a similar site.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not averse to using R, the statistical software environment, I created a package called randomNames that produces random names that can be probabilistically sampled based upon gender and ethnicity codes. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomNames/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to write a [basic windows gui app](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/c__windows_application.aspx).

1. First Step is to read the file.  This [link](http://knab.ws/blog/index.php?/archives/3-CSV-file-parser-and-writer-in-C-Part-1.html) will help you with the basics of reading CSV, if you choose to just do a "format" file where first line is date and then the rest is names you wont be able to leverage that library and will probably just end up parsing the file manually.  This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) will help you out with that.
2. Once you have read all names into a [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz(VS.80).aspx) take the count and create a [Random number generator](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/RandomNumber10272005160549PM/RandomNumber.aspx) and set the max number to the length of your list.  Generate a distinct set of random numbers into a separate collection.

   ** Another option is to use something like [this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread255426.html), which is a random sort method
3. When the button is clicked iterate through your random numbers list and return the name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nix - I am looking into this and will keep all updated.